# Appending URL Parameters to Outbound Hyperlinks Using PHP

Tags: php, html, hyperlink

I did my best to research the available answers and other resources on the web and was unable to find something that meets my criteria specifically.

I am attempting to preserve URL parameters across multiple sites. Here is what I mean:

When someone clicks on website A, they are taken to website B and now have URL parameters (ex: google analytics tags).

Now, on website B there are several hyperlinks leading to website C. I would like to append the current URL parameters (that a user got from clicking on site A to site B) to the outbound hyperlink, so that the user ends up on website C with the same URL parameters as they had on website B.

www.website-A.com -> www.website-B.com?utmparameter1=abc&urlparamter2=xyz -> 
www.website-C.com?utmparameter1=abc&urlparamter2=xyz

I would like to do this with php ideally and code it into the html where necessary.

Comment: I am sure you did your research but we need your code to help you

Comment: This can only work if you are in charge of Websites A & B ... please show us what you have so far.